# Why are object references different after assignment in a static method?

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters

Why `a1==a2` is true after assignment `a1=a2` in the main method, but `a1==a2` returns `false` if we do the same in another static method `m`?

```
class A {};
public class Program
{
    static void m(A a1, A a2){
        a1=a2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1=new A();
        A a2=new A();
        a1=a2;
        System.out.println(a1==a2);
    }
}
```

Output: `true`

```
class A {};
public class Program
{
    static void m(A a1, A a2){
        a1=a2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1=new A();
        A a2=new A();
        m(a1,a2);
        System.out.println(a1==a2);
    }
}
```

Output: `false`

Comment: You assign it in the method, but check the local variable in main method

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is, in java everything is pass by value. In the method you are using local variables and that will not change the actual variables outside method.
You can check this answer for detailed information on [Pass by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/4311413). I hope this will clarify your doubt.